# Webcam only works with luvcview

Tags: webcam

Does anyone know why my webcam would work in luvcview but not in cheese, vlc, firefox, etc?

VLC doesn't seem to capture anything from the camera at all. cheese sorta works for about 2 seconds, but the video is half black and has horizontal lines through it. Firefox getUserMedia example never calls the loadeddata callback.

luvcview displays the webcam video correctly and is able to capture it to an avi file. Any clues on where I should start looking? Here is the lsusb dump of the webcam and the list of supported formats from luvcview:

$sudo lsusb -d 0bda:579f -v

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:579f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x579f 
  bcdDevice            0.02
  iManufacturer           3 11121119-000G824F6
  iProduct                1 USB Camera
  iSerial                 2 200901010001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          785
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB Camera
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 USB Camera
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 USB Camera
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength           78
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000004
          Auto-Exposure Priority
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000177f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x 9
          None
          SECAM - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                27
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {8ca72912-b447-9440-b0ce-db07386fb938}
        bNumControl             2
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls( 0)       0x00
        bmControls( 1)       0x06
        iExtension              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0f 24 01 02 8d 02 81 00 03 02 01 00 01 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1b 24 04 01 08 59 55 59 32 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 10 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 65 04 00 00 ca 08 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 02 00 a0 00 78 00 00 50 46 00 00 a0 8c 00 00 96 00 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 03 00 b0 00 90 00 00 d0 5c 00 00 a0 b9 00 00 c6 00 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 04 00 40 01 f0 00 00 40 19 01 00 80 32 02 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 05 00 00 05 d0 02 00 00 65 04 00 00 ca 08 00 20 1c 00 40 42 0f 00 02 40 42 0f 00 80 84 1e 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 05 06 00 00 05 20 03 00 00 e2 04 00 00 c4 09 00 40 1f 00 40 42 0f 00 02 40 42 0f 00 80 84 1e 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 07 00 00 05 00 04 00 00 40 06 00 00 40 06 00 00 28 00 80 84 1e 00 01 80 84 1e 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 08 00 80 07 38 04 00 40 e3 09 00 40 e3 09 00 48 3f 00 80 84 1e 00 01 80 84 1e 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1a 24 03 00 05 80 02 e0 01 00 05 d0 02 00 05 20 03 00 04 00 03 80 07 38 04 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  06 24 0d 01 01 04
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0b 24 06 02 08 01 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 65 04 00 00 ca 08 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 02 00 a0 00 78 00 00 50 46 00 00 a0 8c 00 00 96 00 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 03 00 b0 00 90 00 00 d0 5c 00 00 a0 b9 00 00 c6 00 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 04 00 40 01 f0 00 00 40 19 01 00 80 32 02 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 05 00 00 05 d0 02 00 00 2f 0d 00 00 5e 1a 00 20 1c 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 06 00 00 05 20 03 00 00 a6 0e 00 00 4c 1d 00 40 1f 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 07 00 00 05 00 04 00 00 c0 12 00 00 80 25 00 00 28 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  22 24 07 08 00 80 07 38 04 00 c0 a9 1d 00 80 53 3b 00 48 3f 00 15 16 05 00 02 15 16 05 00 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1a 24 03 00 05 80 02 e0 01 00 05 d0 02 00 05 20 03 00 04 00 03 80 07 38 04 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  06 24 0d 01 01 04
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           12
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000006
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

$ luvcview -L

```
luvcview 0.2.6

SDL information:
  Video driver: x11
  A window manager is available
Device information:
  Device path:  /dev/video0
{ pixelformat = 'YUYV', description = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'MJPG', description = 'MJPEG' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ pixelformat = 'RGB3', description = 'RGB3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ pixelformat = 'BGR3', description = 'BGR3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ pixelformat = 'YU12', description = 'YU12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ pixelformat = 'YV12', description = 'YV12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 800 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15, 
{ discrete: width = 1920, height = 1080 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/15,
```

Comment: I've found that if I go into cheese preferences, I can change the photo/video resolution to 1280x720 and the camera will work with cheese. Still looking for a way to make it work with Firefox.

Comment: Well, sorta works. There's still a line sort of artifact near the bottom of the video in cheese. I don't get any video issues with luvcview.

Comment: Mine works flawlessly in guvcview, but very patchy and distorted in cheese after reseting resolution.  And not at all in skype.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar Realtek device in my Razer Blade 2015 and it works with everything as long as you have it set to 720p.  It may work with lower resolutions, but that is all I tested.

I have a 1080p USB camera I sometimes use and it was set to high for my USB camera. After I switch it to 720p and then restart cheese it works.